# Can the text in a URL make the link open in a new window?

Tags: url, target

I know that you can use html to open a link in a new page using `target="_blank"`. Is it possible to add something similar to the end of a URL to make the link open in a new browser window (or tab)?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add something to the end of the URL to have it open in a new window or tab.   Whether or not the URL opens is in a new windows is controlled by the browser, not by the URL itself.

The only type of URL that has the power to specify a new window open is is `javascript:` URL.  If you could modify both the beginning and the end of the the URL, you might be able to embed it in JS.  However that only has the ability to open a pop-up window, not a new tab.  Pop-up blockers usually block this code these days.

```js
javascript:window.open('https://example.com/','window-name');return false;
```